# RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation for reinforcement learning

Tags: pytorch

Why pytorch gives me the error for this code? I am trying to implement REINFORCE algorithm.

```python
import torch
import torch.optim as optim
from model_utils import Reinforce
from torch.distributions import Categorical


# train method
def reinforce(environment):
    learning_rate = 1e-3
    gamma = 0.99
    num_steps = 30
    max_episodes = 3000
    num_state_features = 21
    num_actions = 1000

    net = Reinforce(num_state_features, num_actions)
    optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
    net.train()

    for episode in range(max_episodes):
        state = torch.from_numpy(environment.reset())
        log_prob_seq = []
        reward_seq = []

        # generate trajectory
        for step in range(num_steps):
            policy_distro = net.forward(state)

            distro = Categorical(policy_distro)
            action = distro.sample()
            c = action.item()
            log_prob_seq.append(distro.log_prob(action))

            # compute reward, go to next state
            reward, new_state = environment.step(c)
            reward_seq.append(reward)
            new_state = torch.from_numpy(new_state)
            state = new_state

        # compute the return and loss
        loss = []
        returns = reward_seq.copy()
        for step in reversed(range(num_steps)):
            if step != num_steps - 1:
                returns[step] += gamma * returns[step + 1]
            loss.append(- (gamma ** step) * returns[step] * log_prob_seq[step])

        # update policy model parameters
        for step in range(num_steps):
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss[step].backward()
            optimizer.step()
```

and it gives:
RuntimeError: one of the variables needed for gradient computation has been modified by an inplace operation: [torch.cuda.FloatTensor [128, 115]], which is output 0 of AsStridedBackward0, is at version 2; expected version 1 instead.

Comment: I had a look at the reinforce implementation with pytorch [here](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/main/reinforcement_learning/reinforce.py), I noticed that he update by summing over all losses, I want to update model parameter every time step, every loss

Answer (score 0):

First thing to try is to replace all the in-place operators in your code. In your case one of those is `+=`, you can try replacing
`returns[step] += gamma * returns[step + 1]` with `returns[step] = returns[step] + gamma * returns[step + 1]`

Also, PyTorch can give you a little more precise information about where to look for it, you need to run the code with a specific flag (it should be mentioned in the error message how to do it).

Comment: the returns in my code does not require gradient, and I have tried to change to `returns[step] = returns[step] + gamma * returns[step + 1]`, but it has the same error. And follow the flag provided by the error message just output that specify the error occurs at my model, i.e. the `net` in the code.